# Is there any way of changing the text using javascript so that the css keeps on working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically I want to change the text in a div using javascript. I managed to do it, but I encountered a problem: the  tag in which that text was doesn't work anymore for the javascript changed text.

I tried changing `.textContent` to `.innerHTML`

```
<div class="nr11"><h1>11</h1></div>

let lastPosition=document.querySelector('.nr'+player.lastPosition);
lastPosition.textContent=player.lastPosition;
```

I expect for the text ( number 11 in my case ) to be changed with `player.lastPosition` while still having  active for `player.lastPosition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the selector to select the `h1` element instead of the `div`:

```js
let player = {lastPosition: 11};
let lastPosition = document.querySelector('.nr' + player.lastPosition + '>h1');
// or with a template string: `.nr${player.lastPosition}>h1`
lastPosition.textContent = player.lastPosition;
```

```html
<div class="nr11"><h1>11</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the entire `<h1>11</h1>` content.

What you want to actually do is to change the `11` inside the `<h1>`, so you need to select that element, instead of selecting the `<div>` that contains the `<h1>`:

```js
var player = {
    lastPosition: 11
};
let lastPosition=document.querySelector('.nr'+player.lastPosition+'>h1');
lastPosition.textContent=player.lastPosition;
```

```html
<div class="nr11"><h1></h1></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

problem here is you are changing the `<div>`
element text, which is: `<h1>11</h1>`
to your new text.

This means you are replacing the whole thing instead of just the value `11`. To solve this issue you can simply change where you are querying for the element to:

```
let lastPosition = document.querySelector('.nr' + player.lastPosition + ' h1');
lastPosition.textContent = player.lastPosition;
```

This way the variable `lastPosition` will be the `h1` element, therefore you will be changing the `h1` textContent.